# Pandas: Plot running projects

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

i have a dataset (test) containing Information on several projects containing theyer Typ, theier Beginning and theier End:

```
ID   Name  Type  Start   End
1    la    A     2000    2003
2    le    B     2001    2002
3    li    A     2001    2004
4    lo    B     2002    2003
5    lu    A     2001    2002
```

I want to plot the running projects stacked by type per year.

I am able to produce a graph of the Start or the End of a Projekt, doing this:

```
test[(test['Start']>=2000) & (test['End']<=2004)].groupby(['Start','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot(kind='bar', legend=False, stacked=True)
```

[image: Stacked Strat new]

But, as you can see, the different duration of the projects makes a view on the running projects important.
So i want wo have four bars [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004].
The Bar at 2001 should have a high of 4, 3 times Type A (la, li, lu) and 1 time Type B (le). case lo in this case ist not part of the bar, because it started in 2002.

Whats the (short/elegant) solution for that?
And which keywords am i missing that i cant find such a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new Series with `range` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `df`:

```
s = (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['Start'], x['End'] + 1)), 1)
      .stack()
      .rename('year')
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
      .astype(int))
df = df.join(s)
print (df)

   ID Name Type  Start   End  year
0   1   la    A   2000  2003  2000
0   1   la    A   2000  2003  2001
0   1   la    A   2000  2003  2002
0   1   la    A   2000  2003  2003
1   2   le    B   2001  2002  2001
1   2   le    B   2001  2002  2002
2   3   li    A   2001  2004  2001
2   3   li    A   2001  2004  2002
2   3   li    A   2001  2004  2003
2   3   li    A   2001  2004  2004
3   4   lo    B   2002  2003  2002
3   4   lo    B   2002  2003  2003
4   5   lu    A   2001  2002  2001
4   5   lu    A   2001  2002  2002

df.groupby(['year','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
  .plot(kind='bar', legend=False, stacked=True)
```

[image: graph]

For new `DataFrame` is possible use also list comprehension:

```
d = [(x['Type'], y) for i, x in df.T.items() for y in range(x['Start'], x['End'] + 1)]
print (d)
[('A', 2000), ('A', 2001), ('A', 2002), ('A', 2003), ('B', 2001), 
 ('B', 2002), ('A', 2001), ('A', 2002), ('A', 2003), ('A', 2004), 
 ('B', 2002), ('B', 2003), ('A', 2001), ('A', 2002)]
```

What is same as loop version:

```
d = []
for i, x in df.T.items():
    a = range(x['Start'], x['End'] + 1)
    for y in a:
        d.append((x['Type'], y))
```

And then `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Type','year'])
print (df)
   Type  year
0     A  2000
1     A  2001
2     A  2002
3     A  2003
4     B  2001
5     B  2002
6     A  2001
7     A  2002
8     A  2003
9     A  2004
10    B  2002
11    B  2003
12    A  2001
13    A  2002
```